# How to combine results of grep command

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

I'd like to grep a string in a file and combine all the results in one line with command seperated.

> grep 1000 /tmp/userfile

Output of the grep, sometimes the output is 2 liner or more.

> user12:x:1000:user12,user100,user200,user300,user400,user500
>   user13:x:1000:user13,user600,user700,user800,user900,user1000
>   user14:x:1000:user14,user2600,user2700,user2800,user2900,user21000

what I want to achieve is to remove user12:x:1000:user12, user13:x:1000:user13 and user14:x:1000:user14 then combined everyone with command seperated like the one below.

> user100,user200,user300,user400,user500,user600,user700,user800,user900,user1000,user2600,user2700,user2800,user2900,user21000

Hope someone can help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep 1000 /tmp/userfile | cut -d, -f2- | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
```

alternatively (in fact, better), as [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) suggests:

```
grep 1000 /tmp/userfile | cut -d, -f2- | paste -sd,
```

Comment: +1 but you could replace `tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'` with `paste -sd,`

Comment: sweet paste! Didn't know about it. Added to my command-line tools from now on! thanks, devnull : ) Obviously I've just tried it and it works like charm.

Comment: This is perfect and what I need. Thanks a lot Alex and devnull

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/1000/ {string+=$0 ","} end {print substr(string,1,length(string)}' INPUTFILE
```

Might do it.

On every line with the matching `1000` append the line to the string with an added comma. Finally print without the last comma.

It will fail if there is no matching line!